# Tag Synonym: [wireless], [network] -> [networking]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can we get [wireless](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) added as a synonym of [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking)? (Looking through [wireless](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) there are some questions that just need re-tagging)

In addition would it be possible to do the same with [network](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network)? There are only three questions under [network](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network) that would be fine under [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking).

Comment: Done [tag:network].

Answer (score 2):

This has long since been done. This answer is to prevent bumps, and prod mods into slapping a status completed tag on this question if they're so inclined.